# Constraints not working when using block syntax in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I tried to add constraints to a group of scoped routes like so:

```
constraints locale: 'de' do
  scope 'magazin' do
    get '', to: 'magazine#index', as: 'magazine'
    # more routes
  end
end
```

It doesn't make use of the restriction.
Whereas putting the restriction to a single route works as expected.

```
get '', to: 'magazine#index', as: 'magazine', constraints: { locale: 'de' }
```

I tried to use the `constraints` block in different positions, inside and outside the scope block. Without any change in the result.

The [Rails Guide for Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) has this example which I pretty much copied:

```
namespace :admin do
  constraints subdomain: 'admin' do
    resources :photos
  end
end
```

Any ideas what's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without having the whole routes.rb file it is hard to say why it doesn't work as expected.

Is it possible you have some kind of scope defined for locale??

Imagine sth like

```
scope '/:locale', locale: /de|en/ do
  # lots of routes so you are not aware of the scope
  constraints locale: "de" do
    scope 'magazin' do
      get '', to: 'magazine#index', as: 'magazine'
    end
  end
end
```

With this your are actually setting a constraint to `locale` to be either `de` or `en`. The constraint from the scope has precedence over the `constraints` block.

While this is not clear from the rails guide I found a [merge request](https://github.com/rails/rails/compare/master...ferblape:15668-dont-overwrite-scope-constraints) that proves my argumentation.